# Getting issue while writing selenium webdriver Javascript

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write selenium webDriver code for below HTML Code and it is throwing the error like:

> Unable to find element

Can any help on this?

HTML Code :

```
<input class="_3uUUD5" type="checkbox" is="null" readonly="">
<div class="_1p7h2j" is="null"></div>
<div class="_1GEhLw" is="null">Gionee</div>
```

I am trying to select the check box for above mentioned HTML Code and please find my code below. I tried:

```
 bothd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div‌​/div[2]/div[2]/div/d‌​iv[4]/section/div[2]‌​/div/div[1]/div[2]/d‌​iv[72]/div/div/div/l‌​abel/div[1]")).click‌​();
```

or

```
d.findElement(By.className("_1p7h2j")).click();
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Which element do you want to locate??

Comment: Hi , I am trying to select the check box for above mentioned HTML Code and please find my code below . I tried bothd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[72]/div/div/div/label/div[1]")).click();
    or 
    d.findElement(By.className("_1p7h2j")).click();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locate checkbox element wrt `Gionee` text, try using below `xpath` :-

```
.//input[following-sibling::div[text()='Gionee'] and @type='checkbox']
```